# CSS SCSS - Get class property value

Tags: css, sass

I need to map the value of a property from a class to another class.

I'm having the following (what I cannot modify):

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Now, I need to get the "red" value from `.red` class and map it to a new class in the `background-color` property like:

```
.newClass {
    background-color: .red.color
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way with Mixins or whatever in SCSS to achive that.

Comment: Well, I cannot edit the question. The problem is that I cannot modify the .red class because it is in an imported module that I don't have access, and also, I can't hardcode the "red" color in my styles.scss file, so that's why I was looking for a dynamic way to get the red color from the .red class and apply it to the background-color in my .newClass

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable, like this:

```css
$red-color: red;

.red {
      color: $red-color;
   }
   
 .newClass {
        background-color: $red-color;
 }
```

Or:

```css
@mixin red-color($color) {
  -webkit-red-color: $color;
  -moz-red-color: $color;
  -ms-red-color: $color;
  color: $color;
};
.red {
      @include red-color(red); 
     } 
.newClass{ 
    @extend .red;
}
```

I hope it'll work.

Comment: For more information visit: [sass-lang.com](https://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: yes, but I cannot access or modify the first class (I mean, the file where that class is declared). So I can't pass that to a variable

Comment: You can use `@each`:

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: I'm edit my answer. I'm not use `@each` but `@mixin` and `@extend`

Comment: Well, I cannot edit the question. The problem is that I cannot modify the .red class because it is in an imported module that I don't have access, and also, I can't hardcode the "red" color in my styles.scss file, so that's why I was looking for a dynamic way to get the red color from the .red class and apply it to the background-color in my .newClasscolor

Comment: I can't resolve your problem, please visit the officiel site: [sass-lang.com](https://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I use a color function to have a single file or to add and modify my colors

I create a collection if I need to add another array

```css
$app:(
    'primary': red,
    'secondary': #ffffff,
    [...]
)

$collection:(
    'app' : $app
) !default;

@function color($color, $type) {
    @if map-has-key($collection, $color) {
        $curr_c: map-get($collection, $color);

        @if map-has-key($curr_c, $type) {
            @return map-get($curr_c, $type);
        }
    }

    @warn "Unknown `#{name}` in $collection.";

    @return null;
}
```

I import it at the very top of the main SCSS file
and you can use it like this:

```css
.red {
    color: color('app', 'primary');
}

.newClass {
    background-color: color('app', 'primary');
}
```

Comment: It is closer. Well, I cannot edit the question. The problem is that I cannot modify the .red class because it is in an imported module that I don't have access, and also, I can't hardcode the "red" color in my styles.scss file, so that's why I was looking for a dynamic way to get the red color from the .red class and apply it to the background-color in my .newClass

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with HTML/CSS that you cannot change, the option would be to override the existing CSS.

For example if you have

```
.red { color: red; }
```

You can override using `!important` e.g.

```
.red { color: blue !important; }
```

Is this what you mean?

If not please can you clarify and provide the website link.

Thanks.